# ReactNative - Spotify SDK dependency conflict

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native, spotify

I have a ReactNative project with an Android Module used for authenticating with spotify, using Spotify SDK (will be using playback later on).

When building the project, the following error comes up from grandle:

```
> Duplicate files copied in APK lib/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so
    File 1: ...root../android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.16.1/jni/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so
    File 2: ...root../android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.spotify.sdk/spotify-player/1.0.0-beta12/jni/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so
```

Using `packagingOptions` exclude or pickFirst breaks the app, as the two libraries appear to be different (one almost double in size) but with the same name.

What options are there to resolve this ?

Comment: Have you made any progress on this since December, Giannis?

Comment: Yes Ill post an answer now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the following to `android/app/build.gradle` does not seem to have any negative effects, the app has been working without any issues:

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libgnustl_shared.so'
}
```