# How to fix the libgnustl_shared.so file duplicated which in third party sdks?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, duplicates, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

When i used the gradle to build and run the apk, i get the error below::::

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK lib/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so
    File1:  
app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.20.1/jni
    File2:  
app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/app/videosdk/unspecified/jni
```

Comment: one of my modules has the same libgnustl_shared.so file , when i add the ReactAndroid to my project , i get this error tip..

Comment: Here is a clean, non-hack solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35660513/2850807

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally，i move one of the so file to assets,and load it manually before used

```
 String path = getApplication().getFilesDir().toString() + "/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so";
 if (!FileUtils.isFileExit(path))  //move so from assets to another dir
       FileUtils.initSOFileFromAssetsFile(getApplication()); 
 System.load(path);
```

This works not very well , although it fixes the DuplicateFileException bug .
If anyone get the better way pls tell me . 
Thanks!^_^

Comment: Did you ever find a better way than this without needing to repackage one of the .so files?

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? I don't understand what you mean "i move one of the so file to assets".

Answer (score 7):

Cleaner solution is to explicitly tell Gradle that you know about the problem and accept any of these files. Depending on the architectures you support you may need only some of the. You can find details [in documentation](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html)

```
android {

 // some stuff
 packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libgnustl_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libgnustl_shared.so'
    }
}
```

Comment: how without gradle?

Comment: The question starts with "When i used the gradle to build and run the apk"... :)

And do you use another build tool?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this by adding the code below to my `build.gradle`. It's kind of a hack; there should a more elegant fix, like not having to include the React Native version. Ideally React Native would resolve this. I opened an issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9454

```
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask

def deleteDuplicateJniFiles() {
    def files = fileTree("${buildDir}/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.31.0/jni/") {
        include "**/libgnustl_shared.so"
    }
    files.each { it.delete() }
}

tasks.withType(TransformTask) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.doFirst { deleteDuplicateJniFiles() }
}
```

Comment: It was also important for my project to include         flatDir { dirs 'libs' } in the master gradle file (one level up from the one you add the above to.)